# How to push data into the array

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to push new title on button click. I have around 5 button. On each click i have push different message into the array. I am trying following code:

```
public skills: any[];
public firstMsg: string = 'Press Play to start playing';

onPlay(){
    this.skills.push({ title: this.firstMsg })
}
```

But now I am getting error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I could not figure out what mistake I did.

Comment: declare the array as skills:any[]=[];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign empty array at the time of declaration

```
public skills: any[] = [];
```

or

```
public skills = [];
```

Because javascript is not allowed to use array properties over variable which is not initialized as the array.

Answer (score 1):

initialize the array

```
public skills: any[] = []
```